# Access to the full runtime environment within a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that I would like to use together with a monaco editor. The website defines an `editor JS` object that can be used in the developer console.

However, when I define a function within a Chrome extension that tries to use this object, I get `ReferenceError: editor is not defined`, presumably because the extension is running in a separate runtime environment.

Is there a way to give access to the extension to the same env as the console?

The manifest is very simple:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "world": "MAIN",
```